# CanCanCan Authorization on Nested Resources - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-resources, cancancan

**Overview**

I'm attempting to authorize a child object from the parent controller and enforce the abilities of the child resource. I'm using `nested_forms` gem to create the form and the gem's `link_to_add` and `link_to_delete` functionality to handle the child resources correctly (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#usage).

**The Code**

-activity_controller.rb

```
class ActivityController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  load_and_authorize_resource :component, through: :activity

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
  end

  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    if @activity.save
      return redirect_to action: :show, id: @activity.id
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(components_attributes: [:id, :start_date, :end_date, :_destroy, :mon_hrs, :tue_hrs, :wed_hrs, :thu_hrs, :fri_hrs, :sat_hrs, :sun_hrs, :full_time])
  end
end
```

-activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :components, allow_destroy: true
end
```

-component.rb

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

-ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role? 'student'
      can [:read, :create, :update], Activity, person_id: user.id
      can [:read, :create, :update], Component, :activity => { person_id: user.id }
    end
  end
end
```

-activity/new.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @activity do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span12 text-right">
         <%= f.link_to_add "Add Time Period",  :components,
                  data: { target: "#time-period" },
                  class: 'btn btn-prmary add-time-period' %>
      </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :components %>
  <!-- fields for components are here -->
  <div class="row">
     <div class="span4">
        <%= f.link_to_remove "Delete Time Period", class: 'pull-right btn btn-prmary'%>
     </div>
  </div>
<%= end %>
```

There's a lot of code I'm leaving out from the above, but those code snippets are what's relevant. Anyways, the issue is that the form allows me to create components AND delete them when I'm not supposed to. Since I didn't give the ability to `destroy` the Component resource, it shouldn't allow me to delete.

My suspicion is that `nested_forms` gem is destroying the child object (component) by use of the `_destroy` flag and bypassing the authorization from CanCanCan.

Does anyone know of a way to enforce the abilities set on a child object when creating/deleting/updating the child objects from the parent resource?

I hope this all makes sense!

Thanks!

Comment: sorry to see you got no answers, but did you solve it? There are about 99 people who've come to this post seeking answers - if you post your solution i'm sure people would be very appreciative

Comment: @BKSpurgeon My solution was to do the checks manually for the deletion of the resource by explicitly calling "can? :delete" while looping over the child objects. It was a nasty solution but it was the only one I could think of at the time. Till this day, I'd still like to get an answer to how CCC handles this.